# Can not remove a widget from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

The Wordpress site is built on a child theme of twenty sixteen. There's a widget area called the sidebar which is automatically displaying a calendar widget.

**N.B:** The calendar widget is not even added to the sidebar.

I have removed the whole sidebar using `unregister_sidebar(),` but the widget is still there. Also, I have tried removing `get_sidebar();` from index.php file but still no luck. Can anyone suggest me any other way to remove the widget?

Answer (score 0):

Is the calendar a widget listed in the wp-admin widget section?  You might need to remove it from there.  Look at Appearance->Widgets (if you haven't already).  Does this theme use any partials?